# Identical cuboids are rendered differently in Graphics3D when scaled

Tags: graphics3d

When identical cuboids are scaled and shown they appear shifted:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[], 
   ScalingTransform[{10000, 10000, 10000}]], {i, 3}]]
```

Edit: in Mathematica 13.3

[image]

There is no problem, however, if the transform is evaluated:

```
Graphics3D[
 Table[Normal[
   GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[], 
    ScalingTransform[{10000, 10000, 10000}]]], {i, 3}]]
```

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Mathematica v12.2 shows the cuboids unshifted!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I would report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: `Scale` has the same bug:  `Graphics3D[
 Table[Scale[Cuboid[], {10000, 10000, 10000}, {0, 0, 0}], 2], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 40000}, {0, 40000}, {0, 40000}}]`